# Should I create subclasses that differ in ONLY one function in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a base class which is almost fully implemented, except for one virtual function, which by default does nothing.

Now in the case of my problem, I would be having many objects that look very similar, but does behave differently when the function is called.

So the current solution I found is, to create dozens of subclasses that derive from the same base class, with only one public function overridden. This does work but looks silly.

Any decent solution out there?

Comment: looks fine for me. BTW delegation pattern can be used instead of inheritance if you don't like subclassing

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Actually I have no idea about design pattern but this could be a good start:)

Answer (score 3):

It's quite hard to give you hints, when you didn't give us any context (what do the classes do? What's the function name?), but you're right - on first glance it does look silly if you really have dozens of subclasses.

Maybe the solution your looking for is using **function pointers**? If it's only one class, maybe it would be better if you had a function pointer pointing to some global function? With that solution you wouldn't need to derive anything from the base class.

You could also implement all the options inside the base class function and call it with an additional parameters which would hint what version to use. Once more - it's hard to tell what's better when there's no hint on what you're doing.

Comment: If you are willing to go with C++11, the magic phrase is _lambda functions._ That would be my first choice idea.

Comment: @Pawel: I did think of function pointers, gimme a five! But I would like to avoid 'global' stuff since it does not look like OOP:)

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Yes I was compiling with g++-4.7. I'll check out 'lambda functions', the name of which looks so fancy.

Comment: I'm not an expert on compilers, but this feature has also been implemented in at least some versions as "blocks" even before the C++11 syntax. (That is, with a non standardized syntax.) The idea is simple: you can pass a function, i.e., code, as a parameter. This works well for callbacks, sort functions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it doesn't look stupid to me, as long as you know what you are doing.

Of course there are other alternatives.  For example, by making use of [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).  By doing so, you are going to have one context class (something like your original base class), plus one strategy for each kind of special behavior you want to provide.  And when using, in the old way you are going to instantiate the subclass that fit your need.  Now, you will use the same class, and "plug" the correct strategy to it.

It doesn't reduce number of class, nor it is a better design.  It is just a different design.  Take a look to know the pros and cons for such approach, and understand your own problem, and choose one that suit your need.

Comment: Thanks my friend. Whether good for my case or not it will be definitely interesting to learn about stuff:)